# Unable to Set Custom Price or Quantity in Admin Orders

Tags: magento2, orders, adminhtml

I have a Magento 2.4.3-p2 instance running on apache2. When I create an order using the admin backend, I cannot customize the prices and quantities of the products I have added to the order. The update items and quantities button send the ajax request and when it updates the page all of the products' quantities and prices return to their original state.

I looked into both the Magento logs and apache but I have not seen any error being logged. I have also checked in the Magento patches tool for any related bug and have not found my issue there. What can I do else to debug this issue?

#### Update

The issue happened after updating from 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.3-p2, I tested previous snapshots and rolled back to 2.4.3-p1 and that confirmed my suspicion.

Comment: are you trying to set a custom price for each product ? are you using any observer or plugin to change the price of the product?

Comment: Please check if there are any custom plugins or preferences over-riding the classes to save controller.There are chances that when these type of over-riding methods are involved this may happen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, sorry.  I'm having this problem all.  If you post a list of the extensions you're using, I'll cross reference the ones I'm using and we'll see if there's any in common which could be causing the issue.

Comment: Hi Dan, I have already reverted the version of Magento to the previous patch and the problem disappeared. I think in the future I will be checking that upgraded version again and debug that issue.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and the solution was to change the admin max session time.

bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 512000

source: https://argondigital.com/blog/ecommerce/issue-adding-products-to-magento-admin-orders-in-2-4-3-p1/